# windows procrun - OrientDB install

Tags: installation, orientdb, procrun

I've been triying to install orientDB service from their documentation page: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Windows-Service.html

I've manage to create the service the with Instrucctions that are inside.

This is the log the that is giving me.

```
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1596) [  208] Running 'OrientDBGraph' Service...
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:1374) [ 2348] Inside ServiceMain...
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 2348] reportServiceStatusE: 2, 0, 3000, 0
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1127) [ 2348] Starting service...
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( javajni.c:233 ) [ 2348] loading jvm 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\server\jvm.dll'
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 2348] Setting DLL search path to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\server'
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( javajni.c:278 ) [ 2348] Setting DLL search path to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin'
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [error] ( javajni.c:291 ) [ 2348] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1162) [ 2348] Failed creating java C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\server\jvm.dll
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1162) [ 2348] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1536) [ 2348] ServiceStart returned 1
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [error] ( prunsrv.c:1536) [ 2348] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [debug] ( prunsrv.c:844 ) [ 2348] reportServiceStatusE: 1, 1066, 0, 1
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1598) [  208] Run service finished.
[2015-02-04 23:35:54] [info]  ( prunsrv.c:1764) [  208] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

And this is mi PATH

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with OrientDB. You problably installed the wrong JVM (32 bits systems need 32 bits version, 64 bits systems need 64 bits version!)